JasperSoft report iterates a list multiple times
I have a strange issue in jaspersoft 6.20 report generation. I'm using it in java. I am passing a parameter with a list inside. It has 6 elements. As You can see in the code below I am even printing out iteration through the list. I have no idea why it does the iteration n times, where n is the list size.
    <subDataset name="GroupDataset" uuid="92b8d239-921e-4a42-93fd-fe702c199f58">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="memberClass" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="rows" class="java.util.List"/>
</subDataset>

This is passed as a parameter:
<parameter name="groups" class="java.util.List"/>

Here is my detail element that handles it:
<detail>
    <band height="50">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="50" uuid="206d5f03-80b5-4714-b7cd-74594c756c21">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 1_TH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 1_CH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 1_TD"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.proportional" value="true"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="GroupDataset" uuid="abb0b8f6-aa2f-4cb1-9eca-161f89d3afd6">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{groups})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="555" uuid="37c3697a-6bfc-4784-8505-c1cbea115416">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table 1_TD" height="60">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="81" height="15" uuid="9daca62c-6a8f-4cbf-8771-c53cac08488e">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                                <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{memberClass}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="81" height="15" uuid="9daca62c-6a8f-4cbf-8771-c53cac08488e">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                                <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Group index: " + $V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="15" uuid="1a2a5a85-95e6-4926-a8c3-445eaa887c27"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                                <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Klass]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>

